# How can I pass variables to the partials view in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, variables, layout

In the ProfileController I make this method to pass user info to user/profile.blade.php

```
class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    public function profile($username)
    {
        $user = User::where('username', $username)->first();

        return view('user.profile', compact('user'));
    }
}
```

I can successfully receive my data from the profile.blade.php file. But the problem is that profile.blade.php is a component-based layout. And I need to pass the user to a component [A sidebar].

In profile.blade.php

```
 <x-user.master>

    <x-slot name="title">
        {{ $title ?? 'Profile | Reporter'}}
    </x-slot>

    <x-user.partials.sidebar />
    
</x-user.master>
```

How can I send and receive user info from the sidebar view?

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass it using the `:` prefix, according to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#passing-data-to-components):

> You may pass data to Blade components using HTML attributes. Hard-coded, primitive values may be passed to the component using simple HTML attribute strings. PHP expressions and variables should be passed to the component via attributes that use the : character as a prefix

so in your case, you can pass data to components like the following:

```
<x-user.partials.sidebar :data="$data" />
```

Note that you must define this variable in the class component constructor to be able to be rendered

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I do that as well?